# Selenium webdriver-java: how to get javascript tooltip

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I want to get tooltip information enabling on JavaScript. I have tried with below code but its shown null every time.

Java Code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a"));
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a")).getAttribute("data-original-title"));
```

HTML Code is:

```
<tr class="single" name="Tasks_59c777d9-8d16-694a-7307-52caad36d751">
<td>
</td>
<td data-type="custom_task_name">
<span class="list" sfuuid="3840" data-original-title="">
<div class="ellipsis_inline" data-original-title="">
<a href="#Tasks/59c777d9-8d16-694a-7307-52caad36d751">Task Testing</a>
<br/>
Toney Harber
</div>
</span>
</td>
```

I have tried with span tag but this also shows null.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you 2 options try both.

**Option 1**
Please try below. It will return you a list. Loop through it. If there is only one span then you can get the element and then get the attribute value.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@data-original-title]"))
```

**Option 2**
Instead of

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a"))
```

use findElements

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a"))
```

It will return a list of web elements. Loop thorough it you might get more than one element.